# Rails activerecord select fields AS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Help me please. How to do rails select() with AS option?

I can do

```
Model.select([:photo_medium_rec, :profile_id])
```

but this data is extracting for JSON and it will be convenient to work with fields 'photo' and 'profile'. How can I do this?

PS. Only for one field I can do

```
Model.select("photo_medium_rec AS photo")
```

How about multiple?

Answer (score 1):

I would override the `Model#to_json` method with

```
def to_json
  JSON.dump({:photo => photo_medium_rec, :profile => profile_id})
end
```

instead of messing with `select`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...and anyway I need to do this select to reduce number of fields...

Comment: But this is the right way to deal with such things. You dont need to do everything with sql. You have posted some sql related questions and I understod that they were meaningful but this is just senseless! Use the map method Leonid described.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a solution with `select`, I believe you can do that with:

```
Model.select("photo_medium_rec AS photo, profile_id as profile")
```